# Multiple SOAP Connections logout when exit?

Tags: soap-api

I am querying multiple Salesforce objects through SOAP API and thus multiple SOAP Connections. When one of the classes complete querying, I am using connection.logout(). Then, the remaining classes throw

```
[UnexpectedErrorFault [ApiFault exceptionCode='INVALID_SESSION_ID'
exceptionMessage='Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session. Session not found, missing session key: '.....'
]
```

I think the cause is logout(). I have tried removing logout() and it works. The reason I am concerned about is 5 simultaneous connections that can be used while querying (API Limits). Therefore, I need to use logout() and then relogin so that I can use a new connection. I am using the same username, password combo for creating the connection and not sure whether this is the cause.

My question is:

1. Shouldn't logout() be called for all the connections when the
   process is completed?
2. If using the same account is the cause, how
   can I delegate my task to multiple SOAP connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Implementation Considerations](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/implementation_considerations.htm):

> If multiple client applications are logged in using the same user, they all share the same session. If one of the client applications calls logout(), it invalidates the session for all the client applications. Using a different user for each client application makes it easier to avoid these limits.

Even though you call login separately for all the threads/workers they will all get the same session details for the same user. As you found, logging one out will invalidate the session used by all of them.

Depending on how you are implementing this, you could have a single class that returns instances of a Salesforce Session. It only needs to create one for all the workers to use.

When complete, each worker can indicate to the orchestration class that it is complete.

The orchestration class can track active users (in a thread safe manner). When there aren't any active it can call logout. Then when a subsequent request comes in you can login to create a new session.

---

Alternatively, you could just let the session timeout of natural causes. If the workers are starting up frequently enough the session could be almost indefinite in span.

The .NET integrations I've built have been able to share a Singleton instance of a Salesforce Session. This saves time with establishing a session and caching the required metadata. It also handles and dynamically reestablishes the session if required.

Comment: Will this be a way of utilizing parallelism for SOAP API? If not, are there any way to achieve parallelism through SOAP?

Comment: Yes, it will allow for multiple requests. Note that you will still be limited by the Concurrent API Request Limits listed in the Implementation Considerations linked above.